# Can code folding in SublimeText2 be saved?

Tags: sublimetext2

In Textmate I know code folding is remembered each time I open a saved file. Is this possible with SublimeText2 and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Sublime Text plug-in called [BufferScroll](https://github.com/SublimeText/BufferScroll) that remembers most of your settings between sessions.